# How do I make an image a fraction the height of its container

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a column of Grid cells, each roughly square.  Inside each cell, I want to place an image.  I want the image height to be, say, 40% of the height of the cell.

CSS:

```
.pagebox {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 20% auto auto auto 20%;
grid-template-rows: 200px auto auto auto auto;
}

#logo1 {
grid-column-start: 4;
grid-column-end: 5;
grid-row-start: 1;
grid-row-end: 2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pagebox">
    <div>
        <div id="logo1">
            <img src="graphics/logo1.png"
                 style="max-height: 40%;"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the 'style' attribute of the `<img>` tag I've tried what's shown as well as

```
style="height: 40%;"
style="height: 40%; max-height: 40%;"
style="height: 40%; max-height: 40%; width: auto;"
style="height: 40%; max-height: 40%; min-height: 40%;"
style="height: 40%; max-height: 40%; min-height: 40%; width: auto;"
style="padding-top: 30%; padding-bottom: 30%;"
style="margin-top: 30%; margin-bottom: 30%;"
```

None of these change anything.  The logo image is roughly square and continues to be as large as the Grid cell itself instead of being 40% of its height.

How do I do this?

**Edit:** First attempt at a snippet, as requested:

```css
.pagebox {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 20% auto auto auto 20%;
grid-template-rows: 200px auto auto auto auto;
}

#logo1 {
grid-column-start: 4;
grid-column-end: 5;
grid-row-start: 1;
grid-row-end: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagebox">
 <div>
  <div id="logo1">
   <img src="graphics/logo1.png"
     style="max-height: 40%;"></img>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you create a snippet with your code, just so it could be easier to test this?

Comment: You can update your question with the snippet.

Comment: CSS Grid only applies to direct children since `#logo1` is not a direct child of the grid container the styles won't take effect, Also percentage values depend on the parent's width/height and the parent of the `<img>` doesn't any set height/width. Make `#logo1` a direct child of the grid and apply `max-height:40%` to the `<img>`

Comment: @ZohirSalak That explains nicely why what I've tried won't work, thanks.  Do you know if there's any general approach to doing something like this that will work?

Comment: there's no such thing as `general approach` to anything, you can do something in many different ways.

Comment: @ZohirSalak  I understand.  Of the many different ways that might exist to do something like this, do you know of any that will work?

Comment: Your code works fine i suggested the minor changes you need, I'm not sure what you asking for.

Comment: @MihailMinkov I've tried doing that, I'm not sure how successfully.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I missed your last sentence above, sorry.  I'll try that.